# explaining an SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I was given a question in an exam, where I would explain a piece of code from Microsoft Access SQL Query, without any external data or information.

How would I explain the following code in simple/plain English, I just want to get an idea because this is my first time explaining a code:

```
SELECT last_name, department_id, job_id
FROM employees
WHERE department_id IN
(
 SELECT department_id
 FROM departments 
 WHERE location_id = 1700
);
```

Is this a good explanation to a layman:

The following code: asks us to list employees' last name, their job at each department and their job identity. For each department that has a location ID equals/equivalent to '1700'. Would this be a great explanation?

Comment: You should try.

Comment: The following code: asks us to list employees' last name, their job at each department and their job identity. For each department that are located in '1700' or any specific condition. Would this be a great explanation?

Comment: Thank you Igor, I have edited my post and included my answer but not sure if it fits the code or not

Comment: The query returns the last name, department id, and job id for employees that are associated with a department where that department has a location_id of 1700.

Comment: There is layman explanation and then there is technical explanation. Which one are you supposed to give?

Comment: A layman  explanation, but i don't know what the difference is, my apologies. I am indeed looking for a layman explanation (a person that has no knowledge in what I am talking about, as a result I have to explain it to him in a way that can understand it)

Comment: You asked for plain English: It shows employees' last name, their department and their job ID for all departments that are in location with ID = 1700

Comment: @Igor, is that a technical or layman explanation if I may ask?

Comment: @Vlado, is that a technical or layman explanation?

Comment: @oso: unprofessional layman or student - plain English

Comment: @Vlado, what if the explanation was to a professional layman? I should use formal English along with simplicity, would that work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL` means **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage. Another word for "Query" is just "Question". Just about every query is written to provide a set of data that answers a question.

When you're explaining a code sample, or trying to figure out some code you inherited for that matter, a good place to start is to start by trying to figure out what question the results of the query were intended to answer. If you were sitting at your computer and somebody came up and asked you a question, what question would that be that would result in you writing that block of code? Oftentimes, just that question alone is enough of an explanation for a layperson.

Here, I'd say a fair start would be something along these lines.

> This code answers the question, "What are the last names, department IDs and job IDs of everyone whose department is at location 1700?"

When giving a technical explanation, you take it to the next step. How does this code go about answering the question that was asked? This is the nuts and bolts of how the query works, as opposed to what it's supposed to do.

So, technically:

> This code uses a sub-query against the `departments` table, which includes a `location_id` column, to identify all the departments at `location_id = 1700`. Then it uses the department list from the sub-query to get the `last_name` and `job_id` data from the `employees` table, using the `department_id` list as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

As per my point of view, you need to explain the following thing

1. This query type is a subquery
2. This query provides the employee list.
3. This employee list is base on department and only those department need to consider which location id is 1700

So in a short way, you can say like this query give a list of employee which work on the specific location.

I hope you got this answer as correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think a pithier explanation would be along the lines:

> Fetch certain information about employees whose department is at location 1700.

Comment: yes this is a very brief explanation, but what is the difference between explaining it to a layman or in technical terms? Or do they have the same explanation?